# Socket io node js connection issue

Tags: android, node.js, server, socket.io

After some time, the node socket server does not listen to any new connections. Have you guys encountered this problem before? If so, how did you solve?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you show some code? because it can be happened for few reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error after noticing some weird behaviour of app.
The app I set up was a socket server, the server establishes connection after authentication. The problem was that MySql connection slept after 15 minutes every time. So the server fails to establishes the connection since it couldn't able to execute the authentication query.